# Adding and centering arbitrary text in headline

Tags: beamer

I would like to modify the headline to display the name of the conference that I am presenting at (say, "Conference Blah"), and to vertically center this text. I have tried something like

```
\documentclass[8pt,t]{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
\leavevmode
\hbox{
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{2ex}
\end{beamercolorbox}}
}

\title[Short title]{Title}
\author{Me}
\date{Today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

but am not sure how to change the content of this headline, nor to center the text vertically.

Cheers...

Comment: Please put an image of what is to be displayed as output to make your question clear.

Comment: @user jha, if I could display the desired output I wouldn't need to ask the question! If you compile the sample it will display "Short title" in the headline. I want it to display "Conference blah", the place where the presentation will be given.

Comment: Can't you just replace `Short title` in the above by the text you want? Also `\leavevmode\hbox` should be `\mbox` (but you don't need a box at all here, I suspect) and you are missing `%` from ends of lines.

Comment: @David Carlisle, no, because the short title is displayed in the footline using the CambridgeUS theme. Thanks for the other tips...

Comment: @Freakalien it would be easier if you more fully described the problem, and your required output, in your question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`beamer` itself suggests putting the conference name into `\date`.  After all, why would you need the date on each and every slide?  You could use

```
\date[Coming Back -- The Science of Reincarnation]{\today}
```

to have the Conference name on every slide and the date on the title slide.

Otherwise, you could of course write your own command:

```
\newcommand{\insertconference}{Coming Back -- The Science of Reincarnation}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertconference\hspace*{2ex}%
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
}
```

Or you just write the name of the conference into the title verbatim:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}Coming Back -- The Science of Reincarnation\hspace*{2ex}%
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
}
```

Comment: that works nicely, thanks. Do you know how to center this text vertically in the box?

Comment: This would be easier if you could give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), containing the relevant part of your preamble and one slide or so.  These things depend on a lot of things, so without trying it out it is difficult to see what to get.

Comment: all good, got it working nicely. Cheers...